# What does it mean when you say single-CPU operation in multi core CPUs?

Tags: cpu, core

I've been reading about Xeon CPUs in Wikipedia and this terminology has come up. I've tried doing a web search and I can't seem to find anything that can help me clarify my question.

Comment: Some more details of just *where* this came up would be useful.

Comment: To be precise I was reading about the quad-core Xeon 3200-series from this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon#3200-series_.22Kentsfield.22

Comment: A little confusing; I think it may refer to process level where a particular process only gets a single core.

Comment: I see. I think that's the most plausible answer. Thank you.

Comment: One CPU socket - CPU can have multiple cores. The most others support multi-cpu sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Some Xeons systems allow you to put more than one CPU in the same system. Here the term CPU refers to the physical chip, which may have multiple cores inside the chip.

Therefore, if you have 2 quad-core Xeons CPUs, you can build an 8-core system, assuming the motherboard and the CPU support it. The Xeon 3200 series, Wikipedia explains, does not support such a multi-CPU configuration.

Photo of a motherboard with 2 CPU sockets:

[image]

Comment: Okay. So it's referring to the physical chip when it says it only supports a single-CPU operation and not the core in a CPU itself. Meaning I cannot use it simultaneously with another physical CPU chip on the same motherboard. Now I understand and that just makes sense because Xeon is targeted at non-consumer workstations and servers. Thank you.